# Building a Json String in java?

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to build a json string in java but I am a bit confused as how I should go about it. This is what I tried so far.

```
String jsonString = new JSONObject()
                  .put("JSON1", "Hello World!")
                  .put("JSON2", "Hello my World!")
                  .put("JSON3", new JSONObject()
                       .put("key1", "value1")).toString();

System.out.println(jsonString);
```

The output is :

```
{"JSON2":"Hello my World!","JSON3":{"key1":"value1"},"JSON1":"Hello World!"}
```

The Json I want is as follows :-

```
{
 "data":{
    "nightclub":["abcbc","ahdjdjd","djjdjdd"],
    "restaurants":["fjjfjf","kfkfkfk","fjfjjfjf"],


    "response":"sucess"
 }
}
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: For lists you can use JSONArray instead of JSONObject.

Comment: You should make at least a little bit of effort to generate JSON output similar to what you need. Now it *looks like* "this is what I tried so far" is a copy-pasted Hello World-example, and you didn't actually try anything yourself yet.

Comment: Also, it is unclear if you are asking how to get the nice formatting, or if you are asking how to put nested objects and arrays into 'JSONObject`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [**JSONArray**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) and [**JsonArrayBuilder**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html) to map these json arrays.

This is the code you need to use:

```
    String jsonString = new JSONObject()
        .put("data", new JSONObject()
            .put("nightclub", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                    .add("abcbc")
                    .add("ahdjdjdj")
                    .add("djdjdj").build())
            .put("restaurants", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                    .add("abcbc")
                    .add("ahdjdjdj")
                    .add("djdjdj").build())
            .put("response", "success"))
                    .toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson lib.

First create pojo object:

```
public class JsonReponse {

private Data data;

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public class Data {

    private String reponse;
    private List<String> nightclub;
    private List<String> restaurants;

    public String getReponse() {
        return reponse;
    }

    public void setReponse(String reponse) {
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }

    public List<String> getNightclub() {
        return nightclub;
    }

    public void setNightclub(List<String> nightclub) {
        this.nightclub = nightclub;
    }

    public List<String> getRestaurants() {
        return restaurants;
    }

    public void setRestaurants(List<String> restaurants) {
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }
}
```

}

and next complite data and generate json:

```
    JsonReponse jsonReponse = new JsonReponse();
    JsonReponse.Data data = jsonReponse.new Data();
    data.setReponse("sucess");
    data.setNightclub(Arrays.asList("abcbc","ahdjdjd","djjdjdd"));
    data.setRestaurants(Arrays.asList("fjjfjf","kfkfkfk","fjfjjfjf"));
    jsonReponse.setData(data);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonReponse));
```